# Design a System to monitor web services

Tags: c++, web-services, architecture, dashboard

I want to know how to design a system that would monitor my web services status like *CPU usage*, whether the *service is up or not*. I searched it on internet but it shows me different tools. I want to design my own system. A very basic guidance will help me a lot.

Comment: First you would need to build a backend system on your server that can deliver those values. E.g. build a REST api and use web sockets in c++ to download that data and display it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how deep you want to go. In principle you need to store timeseries data, for example rrdtool can be used, then you need to collect a data based on some time interval and last but not least you should be able to present data, graphs for example.
Does it make sense to reinvent the wheel it is up to you, but for such problem there are open source systems based on rrdtool, like Cacti or Nagios.
Also influxdb with Graphana is powerfull in this respect, just to name a few.